# How can I obtain the same result without using any loop?

Tags: performance-tuning

I have a piece of code as below:

```
For[i = 1; t = x, i^2 < 10, i++, t = t^2 + i; Print[t]]
```

and the result is:

```
1+x^2
2+(1+x^2)^2
3+(2+(1+x^2)^2)^2
```

How can I convert it into function program type? That is obtaining the same result without any loop in your code.
Could you help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look up [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html).

Comment: `NestList` or `FoldList` are probably more appropriate if you're looking for successive results

Comment: @IPoiler Many Thanks! I looked up FoldList and wrote as below: Delete[FoldList[(#1^2 + #2 &), Prepend[Range[1, Sqrt[10]], x]], 1] This one can also get the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does recursion count?

```
f[1] = 1 + x^2;
f[n_] := n + f[n - 1]^2;
f /@ {1, 2, 3}
(* result: {1 + x^2, 2 + (1 + x^2)^2, 3 + (2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2} *)
```

Comment: You might want to do `f[n_] := f[n] = n + f[n - 1]^2;`

Comment: Many Thanks! I looked up FoldList and wrote as below: Delete[FoldList[(#1^2 + #2 &), Prepend[Range[1, Sqrt[10]], x]], 1]  This one can also get the same answer.